# Obtain a Value mapped to the Key that matches the Predicate from a List of Map using Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, option-type

I have a list of maps `mapList`.

I'm iterating using nested `for`-loops to get a *value*.

Here's my imperative code:

```
  for(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap : mapList){
    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : stringObjectMap.entrySet()){
      if("SubmittedBy".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey().trim())){
          // Logics to implement
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, I'm trying to achieve it using Stream API.

I need to get a `String` *value* from one of the `Map`s which is associated with a *key* matches ignoring case to the string `"SubmittedBy"`.

Here's my attempt:

```
String submittedBy = mapList.stream()
    .filter(map -> map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(sub -> sub.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("SubmittedBy")))
    .findAny()
    .get();
```

It produces a compile error saying bad return type. How I can fix it?

```
Bad return type in lambda expression:
Stream<Entry<String, Object>> cannot be converted to boolean
```

Comment: Do you want to work with each match in each Map in the `maplist` or just with one (any) of the filtered results? If you want to replace the for-loops, it would be each match, and not just one, right?

Comment: I just need to get the Value from Map once the key matches SubmittedBy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to obtain a *value* mapped to the *key* that matches `"SubmittedBy"`.

You've messed around with your filters, and you don't need a nested stream in the first place.

Initially, you have a stream of maps `Stream<Map<String,Object>>`.

As the first step, you need to flatten the *entries* of each *map* using [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation to obtain a stream of entries.

And only then you need to apply a `filter()`. Operation `findFirst()` would give an optional of map-entry and to transform it into the `Optional<String>` you can map use of `Optional.map()`.

```
String submittedBy = mapList.stream()                                // Stream<Map<String, Object>>
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())                         // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Object>>
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().strip().equalsIgnoreCase("SubmittedBy"))
    .findAny()                                                      // Optional<Map.Entry<String, Object>>
    .map(entry -> (String) entry.getValue())                        // Optional<String>
    .orElseThrow();
```

**Note** that [`Optional.orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) is preferred over `Optional.get()` when you're not checking the presence of data in the Optional (see the [API Note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#get())).

Both methods would throw `NoSuchElementException` in case if optional is empty, by using `orElseThrow()` you're making your intention (*throw if there's no result*) clear to the reader of the code.

---

Regarding the compilation error, as you probably know, `Predicate` is a *function* that produces a `boolean` value.

And to produce a value from a stream, you need to apply a *terminal* operation. `anyMatch()`, `allMatch()`, `noneMatch()` - these are *terminal* operations that return a `boolean`.

On the other hand, `filter()` is an *intermediate* operation, which means it produces another stream, not a value.

For more information have a look at API documentation [*Stream operations and pipelines*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).